# Making arrays of arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, text-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split up a text file and store it into a 2d array using Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174009/how-can-i-split-up-a-text-file-and-store-it-into-a-2d-array-using-perl)

I have a text file with two rows of values **(X-axis, y-axis)**. I would like to store each row's values in an array,  so I have to make two arrays,  and then make an Array of Array from those two arrays, and fetch the corresponding values from the arrays.

Thanks in advance.

#### Example: My text file contains following info:

```
    470    .023

    470.5   .56

    471     .8936

    471.5   .452

    472     .8963

    472.5   .412

    473     .123

    473.5   .412

    474     .965

    474.5   .725

    475     .745
```

#### I wrote this code

```
open (DATA,"text.txt");

@a=<.DATA\>;

foreach (@a)

{

@spi=split (//,$_);

** stored in arrays based on the index values**

@wave=@spi[0..4];

@abs=@spi[6..9];


@new=((@wave),(@abs));

print @new,"\n";

}
```

Comment: What have you done? Do you have anything coded? This is not a 'give me the codes' site.

Comment: I just saw a similar question yesterday.. University homework?? ;-)

Comment: I wrote this code : but not working properly.  

#!/usr/bin/perl

open (DATA,"text.txt");  


@a=<DATA>;  
 


foreach (@a)


{


@spi=split (//,$_);


# stored based on the index values
@wave=@spi[0..4];
@abs=@spi[6..9];



@new=((@wave),(@abs));
print @new,"\n";
}

Comment: @gouthamatla, you should edit your existing post to add that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just do the first part.

```
$perl -ne 'm/(\d*(\.\d+)?)\s+(\d*(\.\d+)?)/;$AoA[$i++][0]=$1;$AoA[$i][1]=$3;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Read through [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS), especially the AoA section. Your array generation code should be:

```
@new=(\@wave,\@abs);
```

Arrays can only contain scalars, so you need to store references (and of course dereference on access!)

Comment: **The out put of the program if i use @new=(\wave,@abs); **

ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)

ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)

ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)

ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)

ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)
ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)
ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)
ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)
ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)
ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)
ARRAY(0x3181d0)ARRAY(0x318398)

Comment: (and of course dereference on access!)